# Google Play Console Crash Notes

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

When looking through the crash and ANR reports in the Play console it would be great to be able to leave myself some kind of notes on each crash. This way when I have fixed an issue but I keep seeing it popup I have a reminder of what I did to fix it and maybe even a URL back to the commit for it.

I know this is possible in the App Store with Xcode for iOS apps but I don't see anything for the Play Store. Anyone else have a way to track these items?